# ImportError: libcusolver.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I've a Tensorflow installation (1.7 GPU) and CUDA 9.0. This setup used to work but after an upgrade yesterday things have stopped working. I am not sure what exactly had changed, but I suspect the installation is somehow broken.

I did uninstall and reinstall Tensorflow but it does not work anymore, throwing the error of:

```
ImportError: libcusolver.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My `.bashrc` file has the following:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin
export CUDA_HOME=${CUDA_HOME}:/usr/local/cuda:/usr/local/cuda-9.0
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/lib/
```

which I am not sure if correct or not.

I suspect this is some .bashrc problem but I am not able to solve it.

Has anyone faced the same or similar?

Answer (score -1):

Probably right with .bashrc problem.

Try adding these to your .bashrc:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:{PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Comment: This kinda messed up my entire system, now I cannot launch any app since it keeps saying PATH does not include it. `Command 'bash' is available in '/bin/bash'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable. bash: command not found`

Comment: Jesus christ, even `sudo` does not work now. `Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sudo: command not found
`

Comment: edited my answer so we append to PATH not overwrite it, try again

Comment: I can't use `bash` anymore, the command does not work. How can I update the `.bashrc`?

Comment: I mean, I've already had a frustrating problem, now I have to deal with another one. I don't know how bad could I downvote you, but you've just screwed my system more or less.

Comment: @Schütze you can run commands by specifying their full path: `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vim ~/.bashrc` for example

Comment: I've fixed that problem, since it is not directly related to this topic I am not going to edit the answer. But thanks. The main problem still exists BTW.